# How to make Laravel (Blade) text field readonly

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a text box that needs to be made `readonly`; I don't want to use `array('disabled' => 'true')` because I need PHP to process the field:

```
{{ Form::text('login_token', Worker::generateLoginToken()) }}
```

How do you add this attribute?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just add it as the 3rd argument:

```
{{ Form::text('login_token', Worker::generateLoginToken(), ['readonly']) }}
```

Comment: Both this and the answer by @Jocker produce the same results. Both work. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

That's how I did it in Laravel 5:

```
{!! Form::text('id', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'readonly' => 'true']) !!}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

For Laravel 5 and above

```
{!! Form::text('name', 'default-value', ['class'=>'class-name','readonly']) !!}
```

In third argument you can pass all your extra arguments in form of an array. This line will result into something like this in html.

```
<input class="class-name" readonly="readonly" name="name" type="text" value="default-value">
```

For Laravel < 5 , this should work

```
{{ Form::text('name', 'default-value', ['class'=>'class-name','readonly']) }}
```

Answer (score 4):

Write the following line

```
{!! Form::text('field_name','field_value',array('class'=>'form-control','readonly')) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
{{ Form::text('login_token', Worker::generateLoginToken(),array('readonly')) }}
```

Comment: If you could please explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it would make your answer even more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Laravel 5.4 along with BootForm, and the only way that it has worked was by doing:

```
{!! BootForm::text('Name', 'name', $name)->disable() !!}
```

Based on the docs of [adamwathan/form](https://github.com/adamwathan/form).
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

U can try...

```
'attr' => ['readonly']
```

Example:

```
$this->add('created_at', 'text', [
    'label' => 'Data do contato',
    'value' => $this->model->created_at->format('d/m/Y H:i:s'),
    'attr' => ['readonly']
]);
```